# Drawing on HTML Canvas need touch capability

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, touch

Hey all my canvas project is responsive so in addition to being able to draw with the mouse I need folks to be able to draw with their finger on their tablets and phones. How do I go about doing this? I've tried adding event listeners but there is obviously something missing. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
        <body onload="init()">



            <div class="container">
              <canvas id="can" width="750px" height="500px"></canvas>
               <div class="header">
                <div class="cross"></div>
                <div id="flake"></div>
                <div id="flake2"></div>
            <div class="message"><h1>HI</h1><h3>Content</h3></div>

               </div>
            <div class="main"></div>


<div id="color">Choose Color</div>
<div id="green" onclick="color(this)"></div>
<div id="blue" onclick="color(this)"></div>
<div id="red" onclick="color(this)"></div>
<div id="yellow" onclick="color(this)"></div>
<div id="orange" onclick="color(this)"></div>
<div id="white" onclick="color(this)"></div>
<div id="black" onclick="color(this)"></div>

<a href="#" class="button" id="btn-download" download="my-file-name.jpg"><p>Download</p></a>

</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
prevX = 0,
currX = 0,
prevY = 0,
currY = 0,
dot_flag = false;

var x = "black",
y = 2;

function init() {
canvas = document.getElementById('can');
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 750, 1000);
w = canvas.width;
h = canvas.height;

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    findxy('move', e)
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
    findxy('down', e)
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
    findxy('up', e)
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
    findxy('out', e)
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function (e) {
    findxy('move', e)
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
    findxy('down', e)
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function (e) {
    findxy('up', e)
}, false);

}

function color(obj) {
switch (obj.id) {
    case "green":
        x = "green";
        break;
    case "blue":
        x = "blue";
        break;
    case "red":
        x = "red";
        break;
    case "yellow":
        x = "yellow";
        break;
    case "orange":
        x = "orange";
        break;
    case "white":
        x = "white";
        break;
    case "black":
        x = "black";
        break;
}
if (x == "grey") y = 14;
else y = 4;

}

function draw() {
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
ctx.strokeStyle = x;
ctx.lineWidth = y;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

}


function erase() {
var m = confirm("Want to clear");
if (m) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
}
}

var button = document.getElementById('btn-download');
button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
button.href = dataURL;


})

var button = document.getElementById('btn-download');
button.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
button.href = dataURL;

});


function findxy(res, e) {
if (res == 'down') {
    prevX = currX;
    prevY = currY;
    currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

    flag = true;
    dot_flag = true;
    if (dot_flag) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = x;
        ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
        ctx.closePath();
        dot_flag = false;
    }
}
if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
    flag = false;
}
if (res == 'move') {
    if (flag) {
        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
        draw();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A touch event works a little differently than a mouse event. When you want to extract the touch position you need to access the touches array. i.e.

```
e.touches[0].clientX //Returns the clientX position of the first touch location
```

You can't just pass the event object into the same handler that figures out mouse click locations. Hope that helps!

**Edit:**

If you want to use the code you already have, you need to make a minor modification. I would suggest rewriting your `findxy()` function to be like this:

```
function findxy(res, x, y)
```

Inside of your init you can modify where you call this function to be one of these options:

```
// Inside mousedown:
findxy('down', e.clientX, e.clientY);

//Inside touchstart:
findxy('down, e.touches[0].clientX, e.touches[0].clientY);
```

That is a simple solution to this problem. Alternatively, you can create a wrapper function for each event type (i.e. touch or mouse) that parses that info out for you and calls `findxy` with the appropriate client coordinates. So your code would be like this:

```
// inside Init:
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
  findxymouse('down', e)
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
  findxytouch('down', e)
}, false);

// wrapper functions:
function findxymouse(res, e) {
  findxy(res, e.clientX, e.clientY);
}

function findxytouch(res, e) {
  findxy( res, e.touches[0].clientX, e.touches[0].clientY);
```

Not perfect, but this will put you on the right track. I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @Chris Franklin do I include e.touches under the init function still?

Comment: I am adding an edit that will explain what I think is the best solution for this.